# CakePHP 3 - Save the same ID on multiple associated tables

Tags: php, cakephp

I have an 'add' method in my 'Users' controller which needs to insert data into four different tables. The relationships between the tables are set up like this:
[db_design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/txzfX.png)

The arrows represents a 'belongsTo' relationship.

If you can't see the picture, the relationships are: Users belongsTo Imobiliarias belongsTo Proprietarios belongsTo PessoalDados hasOne Users. Sort of like a circle, or loop.

My code is currently like this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
        'associated' => [
            'Imobiliarias',
            'Imobiliarias.Enderecos',
            'Imobiliarias.Proprietarios',
            'Imobiliarias.Proprietarios.PessoalDados'
        ]
    ]);

    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')); 
}
```

The problem is: I can't seem to be able to link both the 'Users' table and the 'Proprietarios' table to the same row in 'PessoalDados'. I have tried to `$this->request->data['pessoal_dado'] = $this->request->data['imobiliaria']['proprietario']['pessoal_dado']`, but it inserts two rows into the database table, which is not what I want. What I tried to do is this:

```
if ($this->request->is('post')) {
    `$this->request->data['pessoal_dado'] = $this->request->data['imobiliaria']['proprietario']['pessoal_dado']`
    $user = $this->Users->patchEntity($user, $this->request->data, [
        'associated' => [
            'Imobiliarias',
            'Imobiliarias.Enderecos',
            'Imobiliarias.Proprietarios',
            'Imobiliarias.Proprietarios.PessoalDados',
            'PessoalDados'
        ]
    ]);

    if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
        $this->Flash->success(__('The user has been saved.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'index']);
    }
    $this->Flash->error(__('The user could not be saved. Please, try again.')); 
}
```

Please, how can I link both the 'Users' table and the 'Proprietarios' table to the 'PessoalDados' data that's being saved?

Comment: Possibly offtopic: In your real code you are defining the `associated` option for the `save()` call too, right? If so, please add that to your question, so that future readers do not get confused about how saving associations works.

Comment: @ndm I'm only using `associated` on `patchEntity()`, because that's what they do in the examples in the documentation. Do you think I should use it on `save()` as well?

Comment: I'd think so, yes. Not sure if earlier versions of CakePHP 3 behaved differently, but AFAIR saving was limited to first level associations ever since (even though the docs said otherwise for quite some time), ie with your code, nothing above `Imobiliarias` should be saved. In any case that won't solve the problem with saving the foreign key on multiple tables though, that will require some additional manual saving.